# How to check if a List<String> is sorted matching a specific pattern in Guava?

Tags: java, guava

I'm trying to check if a `List<String>` elements are sorted by the first character of its elements
to match this format
(Blank, Numbers, Letters)
the blank is literally an 8 spaces string `"        "`

I tried this with no avail

```
Ordering.from(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).isOrdered(abc);
```

I wanna do this with Guava, I successfully did this with three `for` loops.

Comment: provide sample input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are not using a natural ordering of strings you will have to implement your own comparator. Here you have te official `Comparator` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). According to the documentation the Comparator interface is:

> A comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some collection of objects.

And it's comparison function will return:

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

You can use the method `from()` of `Ordered` class. This method takes as a parameter a custom Comparator that will do the task of comparing strings:

```
public boolean isOrdered(List<String> list) {
        return Ordering.from(getComparator()).isOrdered(list);
}
```

The `getComparator()` function will return this `Comparator`:

```
public Comparator<String> getComparator() {
    return new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            char firstChar1 = o1.charAt(0);
            char firstChar2 = o2.charAt(0);
            if (o1.startsWith("        ")) {
                return o2.startsWith("        ") ? 0 : -1;
            } else if (o2.startsWith("        ")) {
                return o2.startsWith("        ") ? 0 : 1;
            } else if (firstChar1 == firstChar2) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return firstChar1 - firstChar2 < 0 ? -1 : 1;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I have tested above code by:

```
public void myMethod() {
    List<String> ordered = Arrays.asList("        hello", "1hello", "2hello", "8hello", "hello", "zhello");
    List<String> unordered = Arrays.asList("        hello", "1hello", "8hello", "2hello", "hello", "zhello");
    System.out.println(isOrdered(ordered));
    System.out.println(isOrdered(unordered));
}
```

The output on the console is:

```
true
false
```